# Unexpected behavior resampling time series

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to resample tick time series data in Pandas.

```
time
2014-07-01 10:00:00    1476.29
2014-07-01 10:00:01    1474.70
2014-07-01 10:00:02    1475.28
2014-07-01 10:00:02    1474.65
2014-07-01 10:00:04    1474.64
2014-07-01 10:00:05    1474.15
...
```

I use resample

```
data["2014-07-01 10:00:20":].resample("15s")
```

and get something like this:

```
time
2014-07-01 10:00:15    1472.711000
2014-07-01 10:00:30    1472.376000
2014-07-01 10:00:45    1471.965333
2014-07-01 10:01:00    1470.182667
2014-07-01 10:01:15    1469.607333
2014-07-01 10:01:30    1469.746429
...
```

I don't understand why it starts with "2014-07-01 10:00:15" while I resample slice starting with "2014-07-01 10:00:20". Is it a feature or a bug? How can I make it start with needed time?

So what I need is to compute new time series with values of standard deviation of n previous seconds in given data. For doing this I decided to split it in pieces starting with certain time and then combine them. Maybe there is a better way to do this? Don't want to use iterrows().

Comment: 10:00:20 is pretty clearly in the range of 10:00:15 to 10:00:30, which is what the 10:00:15 value represents. Should the first bin of the resampled timeseries start at 10:00:20 and end at 10:00:35?

Comment: [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) has many arguments, that control resampling. One of them is base. Using this, you can do 'data["2014-07-01 10:00:20":].resample("15s", base =  5).head()' which will output `2014-07-01 10:00:20` as first date. But I dont know it works, and how it affects the resampling. Maybe have a look at this parameter, and hopefully it will help.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks, base helps, but unfortunately I don't know what base to use before resampling, with different frequencies first index seems to be unpredictable to me. However I found out that first index doesn't depend on the length of the slice, so a little weird solution is to resample small slice, check first index, get needed base, and then resample whole data.